# Angles in Quadrant III

Tags: trigonometry

I'm studying maths at the moment and I'm confused about something: when you're trying to find the angle in quadrant III, how do you know when to subtract from 270 or add 180? It seems really simple but I don't get it. I understand this is incredibly basic for many people...

Comment: If the angle is formed between the line and the negative x-axis, you add $180^\circ$. If it is formed with the negative y-axis, you subtract it from $270^\circ$. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Measure the angle as positive when going counterclockwise and measure as negative when going clockwise. If you want to remember this using a shortcut, when the clock moves forward (ie., clockwise), you increase in age, so you add. Do the opposite for counterclockwise.

So, If you are measuring from the negative X-axis in the 3rd quadrant, you are going counterclockwise. Therefore you add the angle to $180^∘$ since the angle measured is positive, relative to the X-axis. If you are measuring from the negative Y-axis in the 3rd quadrant, you are going clockwise. Therefore you subtract the angle (i.e., add the negative of the angle) from $270^∘$, the negative Y-axis.

[image: Figure]

In this figure, $\alpha$ is positive, $\beta$ is negative.